# SVN not working properly

Tags: svn

I am having trouble updating the web root with my changes....

In my local working copy, this file was commited as revision 261.

```
adam$ svn info Page_User.class.php 
....
Last Changed Rev: 261
```

On the web root, which uses a working copy of the same SVN:

```
# svn update Page_User.class.php 
At revision 262.

# svn info Page_User.class.php 
...
Revision: 262
Last Changed Author: adam
Last Changed Rev: 32
```

As you can see the last changed rev should be 261, but it's not happening, and it's not giving out any error.

Comment: try to update your workingcopy

Comment: It just returns this:  `adam$ svn update
At revision 262.`

Comment: If you physically look at the file on the web root working copy, does it contain your changes? When you update the web root working copy, do any other changes from the repository reflect in it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same branch/trunk ? Have you tried to update the root of the working copy and not only a single file? What does svn st -u print out ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've done a complete `svn up` to your webroot, I'd do the following...

- First; run a `svn cleanup` and then try `svn up` again to see if that fixes it.
- If not, remove the offending file and ...

  - do a `svn cleanup` on the entire tree
  - do a `svn up` to get things back to normal